# How to read this type of data in R

Tags: r, import

I am trying to import this text data into R:

```
+1 4:1 10:1 18:1 22:1 36:1 40:1 59:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 -1 3:1 6:1 17:1 29:1 39:1 40:1 52:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 82:1 83:1 -1 2:1 6:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 52:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 98:1
```

Which is

```
<label> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value>...
```

The data stores only those features that are non-zero.So the first observation is Y=1, 4th 10th 18th...83th feature of X is 1.

I am trying to store these label in one vector, and value in a matrix.
The scan or read.table seem not work here. So I need some help to finger out any way to make it possible.

Comment: And your desired output would look like...

Comment: And you've already tried to ..... and that didn't work because ....

Comment: I want to store the label in a vector and value in a matrix.

Comment: No, that is not an adequate characterization of the desired output. Show us, with code, the output that corresponds to the input you've shown, like `my_vector = c(4,10); my_mat = matrix(c(1,1),1)` or whatever.

Comment: Is there only one line, or are there multiple?

Comment: There are multiple, I just post the first two data.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

```
txt   <- "+1 4:1 10:1 18:1 22:1 36:1 40:1 59:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 -1 3:1 6:1 17:1 29:1 39:1 40:1 52:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 82:1 83:1 -1 2:1 6:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 52:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 98:1"
txt   <- gsub("(\\-1|\\+1])","\n\\1",txt)
lines <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
parse.line <- function(line) {
  lst <- strsplit(line, " ")[[1]]
  mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(lst[-1],function(x)strsplit(as.character(x),split=":")[[1]]))
  data.frame(label=lst[1],mat)
}
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lines,parse.line))
```

So this takes your string (`txt`) and embeds CR before each instance of +/-1, then reads the result using `readLines(...)`. Then we parse each line using `parse.line(...)` into a matrix of feature/value pairs, and a label (+/-1) and combine these into a data.frame. The last line binds the data.frames together row-wise.

This might be similar to the other answer but I'm not really sure.

Comment: This is not going to work if we don't know the labels a priori. Are we sure that all the labels are all either +1 or -1? (they obviously are in this example but in a more generic example you may not know the labels I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your data in a single line txt file called test.txt. You can load it into R as a string with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
file = "~/Desktop/test.txt"
read_line = readChar(file, nchars = file.info(file)$size)
```

It looks from what you posted that is space separated so yo can do:

```
space_separated = strsplit(read_line, " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
```

It looks like the labels are the ones that are not containing the character ':' so you can identify their position with:

```
find_labels = which(!grepl("\\:", space_separated))
```

now the tricky bit is to split the character in an efficient way and you can achieve it like this:

```
all_res = lapply(seq_along(find_labels), function(i){
  # Create indexes that identify one label
  if(i == length(find_labels))
    label_subset = seq(find_labels[i], length(space_separated))
  else
    label_subset = seq(find_labels[i], find_labels[i + 1] - 1)
  # Name of the label
  the_label = space_separated[label_subset[1]]
  # Value
  the_subset = space_separated[label_subset[-1]]
  data_frame(label = the_label, value = the_subset)
})
```

This will return a list of dataframes that you can bind together with:

```
all_res = rbind_all(all_res) %>% 
 separate(value, c("feature", "value"))
```

So the output will be a data frame looking like this:

```
label | feature | value
  +1  |   4     |   1
  +1  |   10    |   1     
  +1  |   18    |   1
        .......
```